# JSON string from local storage changes value after it's parsed to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I use this function so I can save my old values from the DOM, compare the to the new ones and display a specific sign if the values differ. I am far from expert in JS, but I think something really strange happens when I convert the `var retrievedData` to json object using `JSON.parse` and save the result(json object) to `var productsRetrived`.

As visible from the picture below I in the first row as a JSON string coming from `console.log(retrievedData );`. Then on the second row I get the object which is supposed to be just a converted version of this string.
I don't know why but instead of that I get an updated version of the string with the NEW value instead of the old one.
Can someone explain why this happens?

[image]

Here is the code :

```
function isInArr (id, price){
  var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("tempThumbnails");
  var productsRetrived = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
   console.log(retrievedData );
   console.log(productsRetrived );

    for (var i = 0, len=productsRetrived.length; i < len; i++) {
      if(productsRetrived[i].id==id){
        //if product is in the local storage compare prices
        if(productsRetrived[i].price==price){
            //if prices match rebuild the json in LS
            changeLS(productsRetrived[i]);
            return 0;
            break;

        }else if(productsRetrived[i].price>price){
            productsRetrived[i].price=price;
            changeLS(productsRetrived[i]);
            return -1;
            break;

        }else if(productsRetrived[i].price<price){
            productsRetrived[i].price=price;
            changeLS(productsRetrived[i]);
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: console.log is "live" in Chrome, at least when used with a single argument (it functions like console.dir). If the object changes, it will show the updated object when expanded.

Comment: The `break` statements after the `return` statements are not likely to do anything useful, and probably will incur the wrath of picky linters. With regard to "retrived", just remember, "e after i except after c".

Comment: @torazaburo, "i before e except after c" rhymes!